# Fixing validation errors in Pelican RSS Feeds

Tags: python, rss, pelican

I am using [Pelican 3.2](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.2/) to generate a blog with RSS feeds. However, running the RSS feed through W3C's feed validator raises the following errors:

```
guid must be a full URL, unless isPermaLink attribute is false
```

One of the offending lines is

```
<guid>tag:foo,2013-08-07:bar.html</guid>
```

It appears that Pelican uses [feedgenerator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedgenerator), but I couldn't find any relevant configuration options.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution is to modify [feedgenerator](https://github.com/dmdm/feedgenerator-py3k/blob/master/feedgenerator/django/utils/feedgenerator.py#L283), changing:

```
handler.addQuickElement("guid", item['unique_id'])
```

...to:

```
handler.addQuickElement('guid isPermaLink="false"', item['unique_id'])
```

RSS already has a `link` attribute; `feedgenerator` currently assumes the `unique_id` is a URL and should not do so. I suspect this is the best way to address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think Justin Mayer's answer is trying to do the right thing, but isn't quite right. At least, using Pelican 3.6.3 and feedgenerator 1.7, that fix produces non-well-formed XML:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false"> ... </guid isPermaLink="false">
```

Instead, I changed the same line

```
handler.addQuickElement("guid", item['unique_id'])
```

(at line 283 of feedgenerator.py, in version 1.7) to:

```
handler.addQuickElement('guid', item['unique_id'],
                        attrs={"isPermaLink": "false"})
```

This turned the invalid RSS that Pelican was generating for me into RSS that validates correctly at http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi.